# Swift FloatingPoint rounded to places

Tags: swift, floating-point, extension-methods

I'm playing a bit with extensions for default protocols in Swift 3.0.

I would like to implement `rounded(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self` for `Double`, `Float`.

Both of these structs refer to `FloatingType` protocol. 
I wrote small extension for `FloatingType` protocol:

```
extension FloatingPoint {

    typealias Exponent = Int // is this okay? how can I write where `Exponent: Int` ?

    public func rounded(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        guard places >= 0 else { return self }
        let divisor = Self(Int(pow(10.0, Double(places))))
        //let divisor = Self(sign: .plus, exponent: places, significand: Self(Int(pow(5, Double(places)))))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

However I can't find the most easiest and fastest method. `Self(Int(pow(5, Double(places))))` so much conversions... Ugh...

The problem is that there is no pow for floating point type, so I need to do lots of conversions.

At 1m calls it loses about 0.04s for the Double extension, which doesn't do `Self(Int(...))`. Is it okay for such method or there is another approach?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? It doesn't make much sense as floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals. So your rounded numbers will usually again have many more decimals. Better to keep them as is for your calculations and only round when converting to strings for display.

Answer (score 6):

First of all one should be aware that most decimal fractions cannot
be represented exactly by a binary floating point number. For example,

```
let y = Double.pi.rounded(toPlaces: 3)
```

does *not* assign the number `3.142` to `y` but the closest number
which is representable in the IEEE 754 format for double precision
floating point numbers, which happens to be

```
3.141999999999999904076730672386474907398223876953125
```

If the purpose of rounding the number is to present a result to the
user up to a certain precision, then it is better to use a number
formatter instead, for example

```
print(String(format: "%.3f", Double.pi)) // 3.142
```

or `NumberFormatter` which is very versatile and can do the conversion
according to the user's locale settings.

In other cases (like working with monetary values) it may be more
appropriate to work with integers only (or `DecimalNumber`) to avoid all rounding issues.

---

Having said that, here are some remarks and possible improvements
of your method.

I have named different implementations `rounded1`, `rounded2`, ... so that all can be tested in the same
program.

I am not sure what the effect of

```
typealias Exponent = Int
```

in the protocol extension is, but the proper way to restrict an extension
is a `where` clause:

```
extension FloatingPoint where Exponent == Int {

    public func rounded1(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        guard places >= 0 else { return self }
        let divisor = Self(sign: .plus, exponent: places, significand: Self(Int(pow(5, Double(places)))))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Of course you don't need a restriction for your other variant:

```
extension FloatingPoint {

    public func rounded2(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        guard places >= 0 else { return self }
        let divisor = Self(Int(pow(10.0, Double(places))))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

The first one looks a bit obfuscated, and relies on the representation
of the numbers as a binary mantissa with an exponent.
I would use it only if it gives a clear performance advantage.

So let's benchmark it! I used this simple
test code which rounds 10,000,000 numbers in the range 0.0 .. 10.0
to 1 .. 8 decimal digits:

```
let start = Date()
var sum = 0.0
for i in 1 ... 10_000_000 {
    let x = Double(i)/1_000_000.0
    for p in 1 ... 8 {
        let y = x.rounded(toPlaces: p)
        sum += y
    }
}
let end = Date()
let time = end.timeIntervalSince(start)
print(sum, time)
```

The results are added to prevent the compiler from removing function
calls whose result is unused, and to verify that all methods give
exactly the same results.

On a 3,5 GHz iMac, with the code compiled in Release mode, I got
the following timings:

```
rounded1:   2.66 sec
rounded2:   2.52 sec
```

so the "obfuscated" method is actually a tiny bit slower.

But we can improve the performance. As you said, there is a lot of type conversions in

```
let divisor = Self(Int(pow(10.0, Double(places))))
```

This can be improved a bit if we restrict the extension method to
the `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol instead. This is not a severe 
restriction, because all current floating point types (`Float`, `Double`,
`CGFloat`) conform to `BinaryFloatingPoint`. The advantage is that
a value can be initialized from a `Double`:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {

    public func rounded3(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        guard places >= 0 else { return self }
        let divisor = Self(pow(10.0, Double(places)))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

That makes it a bit faster:

```
rounded1:   2.34 sec
```

The bottleneck seems to be the `pow` function. Since `places`
will usually be a small integer, it might be worth to use
iterated multiplication instead:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    public func rounded4(toPlaces places: Int) -> Self {
        guard places >= 0 else { return self }
        let divisor = Self((0..<places).reduce(1.0) { (accum, _) in 10.0 * accum })
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Here `Double` values are multiplied and the result converted to
the type of `Self`. This turned out to be faster than multiplying
integers or instances of `Self`.

This is more than 4x faster compared to `rounded3` and needs only
a single type conversion:

```
rounded4:   0.49 sec
```

Comment: weird how the reduce is faster than the pow

Comment: In the last function, if you write `let divisor: Self =` then you don't need any other casts to `Self`. Also, I'd prefer something like `10 as Self` to `Self(10)`, because the latter interprets `10` as an `Int` and then casts it to `Self`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen: That is correct, however `let divisor: Self = ...` might obfuscate the fact that floating point numbers are multiplied, not integers. (Which btw turned out to be faster than multiplying integers and converting the final result to Self).

Comment: @TimVermeulen: With respect to `Self(10)` vs `10 as Self`: I could measure no difference in the performance.

Comment: @TimVermeulen: But I appreciate the feedback, `let divisor: Self = (0..<places).reduce(1) { $0.0 * 10 }` is actually elegant!

Comment: Interesting! Perhaps the optimiser takes care of it, then. If you want to clarify that floating point numbers are multiplied, you could always change `1` to `1.0` and `10` to `10.0`, though I think `: Self` is clear enough. :)

Comment: I chose integers because FloatingPoint can be instantiated from integers (and integer literals) but not from doubles (or double literals). But your feedback made me think about it again, and BinaryFloatingPoint *can* be instantiated from doubles. The updated "rounded4" method is again a bit faster!

Comment: How can this be updated for Swift 4? `Self(...)` give error: `Non-nominal type 'Self' does not support explicit initialization`.

Comment: @TruMan1: That seems to be an consequence of how `$0` is handled in Swift 4 in closures with multiple parameters, and the error message is misleading. – I have updated the code with a version which compiles with both Swift 3 and 4.

Comment: @TruMan1: I *assume* that it is related to the changes discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945967/closure-tuple-does-not-support-destructuring-in-xcode9-swift4. In our case, an explicit parameter list `(accum, _)` is clearer anyway. – Thanks for the feedback!